# Netlogo: How do I make turtles of a specific breed make a decision based on previous ticks?

Tags: netlogo, traffic

I'm trying to build a simulation where commuters can choose to take the car or bike to work. I'm want the turtles to make a decision based on their wait time in traffic from the last 20 ticks e.g. if average wait time is more than 10, they will take the bike to work. I have a plot that shows average wait time of cars and managed to have them make decision on that overall average. However, I have not managed to make each car make a decision based on their own experience. I'm not getting any errors, just not any results.

So far I have turtles owning average-wait-time-list and wait-time.

```
Create-cars ;;(cars are one of two breeds)
set average-wait-time-list []



to-report average-wait-time-sum
;; drop the first member of the list, but not until there are at least 60 items in the list
if (length average-wait-time-list > 20) [ set average-wait-time-list but-first average-wait-time- 
list ]
;; add the number of raindrops created in last tick to the end of the list
set average-wait-time-list lput wait-time average-wait-time-list
report sum average-wait-time-list
end

to record-data  ;; turtle procedure
ifelse speed = 0 [
set num-cars-stopped num-cars-stopped + 1
set wait-time wait-time + 1
]
[ set wait-time 0 ]
end
```

Comment: Looks like part of this question is missing. "I am not getting..."?

Comment: sorry, appears as though my post was cut a little short. What I meant was that I'm not getting any errors, but also no results (empty list) @ThomasC

Comment: There is no obvious error here. You are calculating wait-time for each car in record-data and adding it the the list in the average-wait-time-sum procedure. I suspect you the problem is related to step structure. Can you show us the main setup and go loops, as well as the procedure that calls each of these? Alternatively, put a print statement like "Got to record-data procedure" at the beginning of each procedure to see if they are being run as you expect.